# Binding Image's Source (Window) to UserControl's property do not work

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I want to bind a Rendered "ImageSource" (from UserControl) to "Image" (in Window), but it don't work.

If I place "Image" before "UserControl", it will render one time, but when I change data, the "Image" still same.

ImageView (UserControl):

```
public ImageSource RenderedImageSource
{
    get
        {
            ImageCanvas.Measure(new Size(ImageCanvas.Width, ImageCanvas.Height));
            ImageCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(ImageCanvas.Width, ImageCanvas.Height)));
            ImageCanvas.UpdateLayout();
            //Others code to render this UserControl
        }
   }
}
```

In XAML (Window):

```
<Window>
    <Canvas>
        <local:ImageView x:Name="RenderView" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="44" ></local:ImageView >
        <Image Source="{Binding RenderedImageSource, ElementName=RenderView}" Width="421" Height="614"></Image>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "but it don't work" is not exactly a precise problem statement. However, there is apparently no property change notification for the RenderedImageSource property. So how do you expect the Binding to be updated? And please tell us why you're doing this at all, instead of using a VisualBrush?

Comment: @Clemens: I have used `VisualBrush` in `RenderedImageSource`, And thank you about `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. I figured out it.
Should I change this question's title? And change to what?